# IONIC 4 - The event ionViewWillEnter only fires once

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

Please, I am building a Sidemenu Ionic app with firebase firestore, when it opens, the app shows my collections and data, but when browsing between pages with sidemenu and returning to the data page, there is no data return nothing, I need to refresh a browser page to see the data again. I already checked the life cycle and the ionViewWillEnter the event only fires once.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Evento, EventoService} from 'src/app/services/evento.service';
import { Router, RouterEvent } from '@angular/router';
import { LoadingController, NavController } from '@ionic/angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-eventos',
  templateUrl: './eventos.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./eventos.page.scss'],
})


export class EventosPage{

  
  eventos: Evento[];

  pages = [
    {
      url: '/menu/eventos',
    }
  ];

  selectedPath = '';

  constructor(private eventoService: EventoService, private router: Router, 
    private loadingController: LoadingController, private navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.navCtrl.setDirection('root');
  }


  ionViewWillEnter(){
   console.log(' Teste 3: ionViewWillEnter ')
    this.eventoService.getAllEventos().subscribe(res => {
      this.eventos = res;
      let dateString = 'item.data';
      let newDate = new Date(dateString);
      this.loadEvento();
    });
  }
  
  async loadEvento() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Carregando eventos...',
      spinner: 'crescent',
      duration: 300

    });
    return await loading.present();
  }

}
```

```js
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Eventos</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-card class="card" *ngFor="let item of eventos" lines="inset" button [routerLink]="['/detailsEvento', item.id]"
    routerdirection="forward">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title class="texto"> {{item.nome}}</ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-title class="texto"> Data: {{item.data | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { EventosPage } from './eventos.page';

import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: EventosPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FontAwesomeModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [EventosPage]
})
export class EventosPageModule {}
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


export interface Evento {
  nome: string;
  data: string;
  horario: string;
  local: string;
  descricao: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EventoService {
 
 
  private eventosCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Evento>;
  private eventos: Observable<Evento[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore) { 
    this.eventosCollection = db.collection<Evento>('eventos', ref => ref.orderBy('data'));

    this.eventos = this.eventosCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return{ id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
  }
  

getAllEventos(){
  return this.eventos;
}

  getEvento(id){
    return this.eventosCollection.doc<Evento>(id).valueChanges();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(
private afStore: AngularFirestore,
private router: Router,
) {
this.router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
  if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd && this.router.url === '/main-screen/home') 
 {
    this.storage.get('userInfo').then((val) => {
      if (val) {
        // console.log(val);
          this.profesion = val.Profesion ? val.Profesion : 'popular';
          if ( this.profesion === 'popular') {
            this.allCollectionVideo();
          } else {
            this.getDefaultProfesion(this.profesion);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

It can resolve your issue.