# ionViewWillEnter, ionViewDidEnter not firing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a tabbed page on an Ionic app with the default page implementing the ionViewWillEnter method. It used to work fine but recently I built the app again, the problem happens. My code was originally like this:

```
ionViewDidEnter(){
   this.getData();
}
```

It's not firing so I tried to use `ionViewWillEnter()` instead but it's not firing too.

I moved `getData()` to `ngOnInit()` then only it's working but `ngOnInit()` is not for what I wanted to achieve as I wanted `getData()` to be called everytime user navigates to the page.

Does anyone have an idea of how to make `ionViewWillEnter()` or `ionViewDidEnter()` working again?

Note: The following is my ionic info

```
Ionic:
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.7 (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.9.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 15 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.3.0
   native-run  : 0.2.5

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.11.3
   OS     : Windows Server 2016
```

Comment: what is your ionic version

Comment: @ORBIT I'm using ionic 4

Comment: can u please run "ionic info" command in your project path in terminal.

Comment: maybe u can use. router.events in Router angular directive for your purpose. run your function on your specific page or component.

Comment: Can you please follow this. 
    [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57718870/ionic-4-the-event-ionviewwillenter-only-fires-once/57815966#57815966 ]

Comment: @HassanAli I tried that one but it didn't work

Comment: I found an issue in ionic CLI but I'm not sure if it's related as the only thing doesn't work for mine is ionViewDidEnter and ionViewWillEnter https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4145